# Plotting The derivative of the associated Legendre function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I was wondering why I was having difficulty plotting
`∂[LegendreP[l, m, Cos[x]], x]`, where $l\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\{-l,~-l+1,\cdots,l-1,~l\}$ as per usual for this function. I even tried the equivalent `Subscript[∂, x]LegendreP[l, m, Cos[x]]` (I am aware that doesn't come out neatly on this page, but that's what copying the code gives after pasting it).

Is it a variable type issue and if so, how can I get around this?

Comment: The principal difficulty seem to be correct syntax for the derivative: `D[LegendreP[L0, m, Cos[x]], x]`

Comment: Use `D[LegendreP[l, m, Cos[x]], x]` not `∂[LegendreP[l, m, Cos[x]], x]` The 1st form gives `-(1/(-1 + Cos[x]^2))((-1 - l) Cos[x] LegendreP[l, m, Cos[x]] + (1 + l - m) LegendreP[1 + l, m, Cos[x]]) Sin[x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `m` to depend on `L`, something like this. But when `L=0` there is a problem so need to check for it.

[image]

```
ClearAll[L0, m, x];
Manipulate[
 expr = D[LegendreP[L0, m, Cos[x]], x];
 If[L0 != 0,

  Plot[expr, {x, -L0, L0}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"f(x)", None}, {"x", "D[LegendreP[L0,m,Cos[x]],x]"}}, 
   ImagePadding -> 50, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PlotStyle -> Red],

  Plot[expr, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"f(x)", None}, {"x", 
      "D[LegendreP[L0,m,Cos[x]],x]"}}, ImagePadding -> 50]
  ],

 {{L0, 1, "L"}, -10, 10, 1, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 1, "m"}, -L0, L0, 1, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```